# How to paginate data from server without using library in recyclerview?

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView with CardView Adapter. I want to fetch data from url with several pages. How do I paginate data?

When the user is done with the first page I want a progressbar at the bottom of the page(Like Facebook app). I have to do this without using any libraries. Does anyone have a solution for this?

P.S : I dont have any url for pagination. Please send url too
(I am just a beginner.Please be specific while explaining)

Comment: Are you asking about automatically retrieving the next page of data from the server when the user scrolls to the bottom of the recyclerview?

Comment: Exactly. I do have another doubt whether to use swipeRefreshLayout or something else for placing progress at the bottom. @guy

Comment: So you do have a url in which you can increment the page number to get the next page of results?

Comment: Nope. I dont have any url.@guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially what you need to do is detect the point at which the user has scrolled far enough that you need to get the next bit of data. In order to do that you'll have to extend RecyclerView's OnScrollListener and override the OnScrolled method.

You can check out the code and detailed solution with explanations about how to do this for different layout managers here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

As far as your requirement of a URL that you can use to test pagination, I'd suggest something like TMDB. The full documentation is available here: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started

You'll have to sign up for an API key. You could start with a simple endpoint like `api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=<your api key here>&page=<page-number>`

Comment: I couldn't able to create multipage api. How could i do that?

Comment: Did you register for the TMDB API key and try the URL I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I do generated api     https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=11bf40888e9502432c19b39672a14062

Comment: Then what is the issue? I don't understand.

Comment: No issues. Thanks you very much